# Monad use in mongodb access

Tags: mongodb, haskell, monads

In the following code, I partially apply a DB connection (called `sharedPipe`) to some DB access functions. When I have the last line of the DB access be `liftIO $ PutStrLn "something"`, I can have a return type of `IO ()`. But if I want to return the results from the function, I must return a type `Action IO ()`. When I run the code, the compiler tells me the expected type of the DB connection is `IO Pipe`, and its actual type is `Action IO Pipe`, because I access the `connection <- passedInConnection` in the same do block that returns the `Action`. How can I access the DB connection as an `IO Pipe` and not an `Action IO Pipe`?

```
sharedPipe = runIOE $ connect (host "127.0.0.1")

run p dbName act = access p master (pack dbName) act

get' :: IO Pipe -> String -> [String] -> Action IO [String]
get' sharedPipe dbName args = do
    pipe <- liftIO sharedPipe
    cursor <- run pipe dbName $ DB.find (select [] (pack $ head args))
    docs <- rest (case cursor of
                    Right c -> c)
    parseDocs docs
    --liftIO $ putStrLn "something"

get :: String -> [String] -> Action IO [String]
get = get' sharedPipe
```

Comment: It looks like `pipe <- sharedPipe` should be `pipe <- liftIO sharedPipe`, since the do-block is in the `Action IO` monad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reduced your code block to the problem components. The following fixes your problem by using `liftIO`:

```
import Database.MongoDB
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

sharedPipe :: IO Pipe
sharedPipe = runIOE $ connect (host "127.0.0.1")

get :: [String] -> Action IO [String]
get = get' sharedPipe

get' :: IO Pipe -> [String] -> Action IO [String]
get' sharedPipe args = do
    pipe <- liftIO $ sharedPipe
    return []
```

As mentioned by Daniel Díaz Carrete, your function `get'` is in the `Action (IO a)` monad transformer stack. `sharedPipe` is of type `IO Pipe`, and since `Action m a` is an instance of `MonadIO`, you can use simply the `liftIO` to run the action and retrieve your pipe.

Also, for reference, your code block doesn't appear usable with the current version of `Database.MongoDB`. `run`, specifically, is called `access`.

Comment: This did help, but the fundamental problem was that I needed to call `access` on a function that returned an `Action`.